# Subset of Columns

Tags: pandas, shapefile, geopandas, geography

df: I have origin-destination id information ( like 1001, 1002,...) and other informations such as trade between each pairs.

df2: I have just Economics Regions origin-destination id information.( so, I know which id in df is Economic Regions).(For instance 1005, 1007.. are economic regions )

Aim: I just want to get informations between Economic regions from df.

How I can select just Economic regions csd in my df data. I need select as origin-destination pairs.

I spent so much time on it. I am new to Phyton. Any help would be appreciated.

For instance, df:

```
    Origin     Destination
0    1001         1001
1    1002         1002
2    1003         1003
3    1004         1004
4    1005         1004
5    1006         1005
```

df2:

```
    ER
0  1001
1  1002
2  1003
3  1004
```

Aim to get:

```
     Origin  Destination
0    1001         1001
1    1002         1002
2    1003         1003
3    1004         1004
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

We can try use `isin`

```
df = df[df.id.isin(df2.id)]
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I check as a pair of Origin-Dest ?